# setVisibility not working even in uiThread

Tags: android

I want to toggle visibility of some elements. I have read some Q/A that the main problem was doing this in main thread but I am running the code in `runOnUiThread` but not works yet:

```
 TextView progress;
 TextView registrationFailed;
 Button tryAgainRegistration;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);
        sp = this.getSharedPreferences("settings", this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        progress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        registrationFailed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registrationFailed);
        tryAgainRegistration=(Button) findViewById(R.id.tryAgainRegistration);


        Setstat(0);  // For test
   }

public void Setstat(final Integer a){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("progress",a.toString()); // It shows 0 and 1 correctly
            if (a == 1) {
                progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                registrationFailed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tryAgainRegistration.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                registrationFailed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tryAgainRegistration.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

for more details this is the UI xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="Registeration in progress"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/registrationFailed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="Registeration in progress"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Try again"
    android:id="@+id/tryAgainRegistration"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

Comment: If you call this method from onCreate it should already be running in the UI thread. I think this makes it just more complicated. As far as i know runOnUiThread has to be called on an activity anyway. So i think it doesn't change anything here.

Comment: Thank you @einUsername this is simple version of my code. I call Setstat from various methods but non of them work. I can just see the LOG of 0 and 1.

Comment: Your example scenario works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My specific problem was that I had created the XML view using `constrainLayout` but modified it manually without removing original settings of constrainLayout. So I guess the layout was not well recognized by system Ui.

In fact I made a mistake by manually renaming `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` to  `LinearLayout` as the root element.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Registration"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_registration">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running this in on create.
Just to see if it is because of the threads or not:

```
findViewById(R.id.yourView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The runOnUiThread method needs a reference to the activity.
Otherwise it doesn't know which one the UI thread is.
You might get a warning about memory leaks. If you are worried about that, google for WeakReference.

```
((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
```

Comment: `(findViewById(R.id.progress)).setVisibility(View.GONE);` not working in onCreate too.

Comment: That's really weird, maybe it's a bug in Android Studio. Try Build>Rebuild Project and File>Invalidate Caches/Restart. Then, check again for errors in logcat. And finally try Tools>Layout Inspector, maybe you find something there.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestions made me review the structure again. I found the problem and I will post the answer for later uses.